# How to use Bootstrap modal using the anchor tag

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have included following script an

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

My ajax call PHP page code is:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){
    $name = $row['first_name'];
    $name_string = "<a edit_id='name_".trim($name)."' href='#' data-target='#myModal' data-toggle='modal'>{$name}</a>";
    //onClick=\"click_today('{$name}');\"
    $result_array[] = array($row['id'], $name_string, $row['last_name'], $row['job_title'], $row['salary']);
}
```

in my above php file I have passed table data into called page, here I have used  for click the name and show the modal this is actually my need but modal does not show instead of it will show following output
[image]

I don't know what is the problem I have included bootstrap 3.3.6 js and css files

pls let me know my mistake

Comment: because of my need when i click each firstname link the modal display the record from their firstname

Comment: Specify the data target in your tag. See below answer

Answer (score 0):

Specify the data target in your tag

```
$name_string = "<a edit_id='name_".trim($name)."' href='#'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>{$name}</a>";
```

If you use hide, then by using jquery use

```
$('#MymModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: i have found error bro in my html code i have use class="modal hide fade" this 'hide' problem i have removed this hide and simply call class from modal fade it has work correct thanks bro your suggestion

Comment: If you use hide, then by using jquery use $('#MymModal').modal('show');

Answer (score 0):

if you use anchor tag to use href="#your modal id"

change your code like

```
$name_string = "<a edit_id='name_".trim($name)."' href='#myModal'  data-toggle='modal'>{$name}</a>";
```